# JSP can't resolve import of org.apache.commons.lang

Tags: java, jsp, apache-commons, url-encoding, stringescapeutils

I am trying to include the library StringEscapeUtils and everything that I can find indicates that I can import the Apache Org page as follows:

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils" %>
```

however, I can only resolve the URL down to this:

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.*" %>
```

and when I do that, the compile still cannot resolve `StringEscapeUtils`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not a URL. It's a path. Are you using an IDE? a servlet container? which? Where's the jar file? what is the classpath?

Comment: Hi Yuval F, Sorry for the terminology confusion.  Brabster got me going with my other related question.  As for your question, I am using Eclipse and as I added the statement, Eclipse was 'keeping up' with my import statement until I added '.lang', at which point it red-lined my path.  I have switched over to using java.net.URLEncoder per the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, imports are not references to URLs, they are references to Java packages. To import that class, you will need to include the commons-lang JAR in your classpath.

If this is related to [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351978/how-to-convert-entites-of-jsp-request-arguments-for-html-form-textarea), you do not appear to need an external library, as I explained there.